# How to find quadratic equation when the complex roots are given?

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

> For example, $x= -4+0.4i$, $x= -4 - 0.4i$

How do I find remove the complex $i$ and find the quadratic formula ?

Someone told me that the formula is $x^2$ - (sum of roots)$x$ + (product of roots) = $0$

But this formula does not resonate with me well as it is out of the blue and I don't understand it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember how you solve a quadratic equation by factoring?

$$(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = 0 $$
$$x -r_1 = 0 \;\;\;\;\;\textrm{ or }\;\;\;\;\;x-r_2 = 0$$
$$x = r_1 \;\;\;\;\;\textrm{ or }\;\;\;\;\;x = r_2$$

So just reverse this process. Simplify the product on the first line if you want to, which then becomes

$$x^2 - r_1x -r_2x + r_1r_2 = 0$$
$$x^2 - (r_1 + r_2)x + r_1r_2 = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

The formula your friend gave you is a special case of [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). So, using this formula, we find that the quadratic equation is $x^2-(-4+0.4i+-4-0.4i)x+(-4+0.4i)(-4-0.4i)=x^2+8x+16.16$. Multiply this equation by a number $a$ to get all the possible parabolas with these two roots.